# Difference between Testng framework and cucumber framework in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, frameworks

Is testng a framework if so what is the difference between Testng framework and cucumber framework . Can we use more than one framework in one project ?
Both comes in bdd approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes TestNG is a framework.

`Cucumber` is a tool that supports `Behaviour-Driven Development (BDD)` Approch.

`TestNG` having its own approach to maintain and execute test cases. You can make groups of tests , set priority of tests, add dependency of other tests, parameterized tests.